# NSExtension Share Extension Not Showing App Icon on Device

Tags: ios8-share-extension

My Objective-C iOS share extension is not showing the app icon when you select share from Google Maps (or anywhere else) on the device, even though it's working on the simulator.  I've read a few similar posts and I've tried making the main project assets also a target of the share extension, cleaning the project, deleting and re-installing the app, re-booting the phone, even changing the share extension bundle identifier.  None of them get the icon to show.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I really loathe Xcode.  Say what you want about Microsoft, but I never had anywhere near the amount of issues with their development tools.  Anyway, here's the workaround I finally found...

- Go to the developer center and delete the auto generated identifier associated with the share extension
- Rename the bundle identifier for the share target (I added a '2' to the end)
- Clean the Xcode project
- Exit Xcode
- Restart Xcode and build and run your project

Hope this works for others too.